# C# WPF Grid Resize When Adding Content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid inside a scrollviewer that I want to re-size as content is added. Currently it doesn't resize if I add a button to it out of view. Which is odd... but not my main concern. My main concern is if I add elements into the grid programmaticly would it resize. If not then what should I use to make it resize.

Here is the current idea

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="266" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434">
    <Menu Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="145"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="246" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid Height="173" Width="100"/>

    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you try to use the Grid is not the way it works. To have it working you have to define at least either row or column. Then you can place your controls in specific rows and columns. It looks like in your case you only need single row and column.
It is in the row/column definition where you define the size and whether it should resize or not.

```
<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="246" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid>
        <!--Define rows and columns-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Place a control in the grid-->
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The `Height` and `Width` properties are set to `Auto`. It means they will readjust themselves to the size of the content. For instance, in the example above the button's height and width are both set to 100. It means the row and the column will maintain these values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to remove Width="434" from your DockPanel and other widths from you control Width="100", if width is fixed than you cant resize you should remove width property, i hope that works

EDIT:
You can use StackPanel enstead Grid, your problem was when you addin some element it is adding top of another element.
xaml code:

```
 <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
    <Menu Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="MenuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="145"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
        <StackPanel Name="uiStack" Orientation="Vertical">


        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</DockPanel>
```

codeBehind:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uiStack.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "Button1" });
        uiStack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Button1" }); 
    }
```

Comment: For all intents and purpose I am trying to have a variable vertical axis (so height). Also yes I've tried setting everything to auto. I am unable to have the grid resize to content if I add it manually so I assume it would be the same programically